# flex how to resize videoplayer when window scale?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I use the

```
<s:VideoDisplay>
```

It is embedded into a browser and takes 100%, 100%  of the browser
This works initially good: whatever the initial size of the browser is, it takes 100%, 100% of the browser.

Problem comes when I resize the browser window: 
The SWF always takes 100%, 100% of the window, but video inside VideoDisplay does not !

I tried to add some eventListeners like:

```
protected function application1_resizeHandler(event:ResizeEvent):void {
    videoDisplay.percentHeight = 100;
    videoDisplay.percentWidth = 100;
    videoDisplay.invalidateDisplayList();   
}
```

No success !
To summerize:

SWF is always 100%, 100%: 
 - so this is not a problem of embedding the swf into html

- the initial videoPlayer size is always good
- problems comes when I do resize the browser: looks like videoPlayer does not refresh (if I do refresh the browser, then video is perfect !)

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

try this it works for me :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" >
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:VGroup verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="center" height="100%" width="100%" >
        <s:VideoDisplay id="myVid" height="100%" width="100%" source="idir.mp4" autoPlay="true"/>
    </s:VGroup>
</s:Application>
```